# Python threading proper way

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to Python Threading, Threading as well, and I have never used it. That's how I am using it.

I have a class `Source` and I want that its method `evaluate` is executed in a thread. The `evaluate` method call a Utility function `increment` defined outside the class which increments a global variable. Incrementing the global variable should be performed in a critical section. Also, after some processing, I need to pause the thread for some seconds. That's how I implement it:

```
import threading
caseGT = threading.Lock()
GT = 0
def increment():
    with caseGT:
        GT = GT + 1

class Source:
    def evaluate(self):
        for (someCondition):
            ...
            ...
            increment()
            ...
            ...
            time.sleep(2)
```

That's how I am calling the method evaluate:

```
s = Source(....)
Thread(s.evaluate()).start()
```

I am getting valid result with testdata. But my questions are:

1. I am wondering whether it is going to work properly when many threads are doing to work at the same time ?
2. Also, is there a better way to write use threading in this situation ?

Comment: Have you ever heard about python GIL?

Comment: nopes, never heard of

Comment: What is your use case for using threading? performance or parallel execution effect ?

Comment: the thing is that i have thousands of URLs for RDF documents and I have to download these RDF documents. Some may take time while others may be quick. The sleep time is so that for a particular Pay Level Domain, it waits say 1 minute before performing a call on the same PLD. So the use of threading is to enable download of several files at the same time and to prevent a blocking downloading from affecting others

Comment: plz, investigate concurrent module

`from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor`

or you can use `Pool` class from `multiprocessing.dummy` [this module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy)

Comment: @IlyaVishnevsky, per you knowledge, will my implementation produce any invalid results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I like to use threading is to use an iterable to launch threads.

```
workers = []
for item in some_list:
    worker = Thread(target=some_func, args=(item,))
    workers.append(worker)
    worker.start()
for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```

So I imagine that in your context you would want to define a method within `Source` that lets you pass an iterable and then start threads using items from that iterable as arguments. In your context with just one argument going to the `evaluate` method your implementation is fine. But I think scaling to multiple threads for the same method could be a problem with that usage.

Comment: why do you keep a records of the Threads, in my case, I just need the threads to start do their work, increment the global variable and die

Comment: I do it mainly so that I can use the `join` method so that they properly block and are terminated upon completion.